# Can I flag a Wrong downVote/UpVote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have observed that people do down voting to question/answer so as to improved quality but there can be scenario like it is not appropriate, is there any facility available on SFSE so that one can flag such down votes.

> Also we do not provide reason when we do down vote to question/answer!

Lets say I asked question or answered to some question and somebody has down voted, I found that it is not appropriate if I have to flag that can I do that?

If not it is good idea to have such facility on SFSE to flag such questions/answers! Nobody feels good if he/she receives a down vote after spending time answering a question or putting question on forum.

Also it will be good if someone is doing Down Vote He/She put explanation in comment, rather if SFSE put it as a mandatory to have description if some one is downvoting to a question/answer, so as user should know what should be improved! that will also help to improve quality of question or answer

Thoughts!

Thanks,
Nachiket

Comment: still looking for other answers ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I agree that some votes are surprising or would be more contributing if they were combined with a meaningful comment, flagging these questions or answers will not enable anyone to do more than you can do yourself.

- Comment when you think something can be improved.
- Express your own opinion with your own vote.